# Python decodes carriage return as line feed

Tags: python

I am struggling to find an explanation on why python decodes carriage return as line feed.

I have here for the example a text file of one line containing a Carriage Return character (\r).
If I open it as a text file specifying the encoding, I do not find the same string that if open the file in binary mode and the decode it with this same encoding.

Indeed when I open the file in text mode, the CR character is replaced with a Line Feed one (\n).

Why ?

```
with open("text.txt", encoding="utf-8", mode="r") as f:
    txt = f.read()
txt
>>>'4312;"blabla";";\n";"blabla2"\n'

with open("text.txt", mode="rb") as f:
    txt2 = f.read()
txt2.decode("utf-8")
>>>'4312;"blabla";";\r";"blabla2"\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `open` function's universal newline mode, enabled by default, automatically normalizes `'\r'` and `'\r\n'` into `'\n'`. You can use the `newline=''` argument if you prefer that the original line endings be preserved instead:

```
with open("text.txt", encoding="utf-8", mode="r", newline='') as f:
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open):

> `newline` controls how universal newlines works (it only applies to text
>   mode). It can be None, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and `'\r\n'`. It works as
>   follows:
>
> - On input, if `newline` is `None`, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in `'\n'`, `'\r'`, or `'\r\n'`, and these are
>     translated into `'\n'` before being returned to the caller. If it is `''`,
>     universal newline mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to
>     the caller untranslated. If it has any of the other legal values,
>     input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the line
>     ending is returned to the caller untranslated.
> - On output, if `newline` is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, `os.linesep`. If
>     newline is `''`, no translation takes place. If `newline` is any of the
>     other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the
>     given string.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with encoding.

When you open the file in "r" (text) mode, then universal newline support applies unless you specify something else. That works as follows:

> When reading input from the stream, if newline is None, universal
>   newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or
>   '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to
>   the caller.

At https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html under class `io.TextIOWrapper`.

When you open the file in "rb" (binary) mode, then you get exactly what is in the file.

It looks like your file has `\r` in it and when you read it in text mode, you are getting it normalized to `\n`. But in binary mode it is (of course) not normalized, so you get the inconsistent EOLs that are actually in the file.

Answer (score 3):

The full list of default parameter of open are:

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True)
```

The `newline=None` parameter is behind the behavior that you noticed. This parameter when not specified (a.k.a newline=None) results on activating "Universal newline mode". As stated in the documentation, [here](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open), this means that `\r\n` will be translated to `\n` automatically:

> On input, if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled.
>   Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are
>   translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller.

When you open the file with `mode=rb`, the data is loaded as bytes and won't be decoded, thus the automtic translation of `\r` to `\n` won't be done.

> Files opened in binary mode (including 'b' in the mode argument)
>   return contents as bytes objects without any decoding

---

More on universal newline support in [PEP 278 -- Universal Newline Support](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/).